# Issues in running a NodeJS code that supports both javascript and typescript code using pm2

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a NodeJS project which is hosted on pm2. I have never worked with pm2. I want to convert my NodeJS project to typescript, gradually. I have some files converted to typescript. I have made my config settings in such a way that my `/built` folder contains only those .js file for which I have created a custom .ts file. I want my project to run javascript and typescript files together.

This is my tsconfig.json -

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    
      "module": "commonjs",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
      "rootDir": "./src/",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
      "moduleResolution": "node",                          /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    
      "typeRoots": [
        "./node_modules/@types",
        "./src/types"
      ],                                                    /* Specify multiple folders that act like './node_modules/@types'. */
      // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
  
      "allowJs": false,                                     /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */
      "checkJs": false,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
      "outDir": "./built",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
      "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
  
      "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
      "noImplicitAny": false,                               /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
      "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": [
          "node_modules",
          "node_modules/**/*",
          "./node_modules",
          "./node_modules/*",
          // "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
          // "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
          "./built/**/*"
        ]
  }
```

and in my package.json this is how my scripts look like -

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=staging node src/index.js",
    "type": "module",
    "start:staging": "cross-env start ecosystem.staging.config.json --no-daemon",
    "start:production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node src/index.js",
    "start:preprod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=preprod node src/index.js",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development LOGGLY_ACTIVE=false ts-node-dev --watch ./built -P tsconfig.json built/index.js",
    "test": "jest -i",
    "test:watch": "jest -i --watchAll",
    "coverage": "jest -i --coverage",
    "coverage:coveralls": "jest -i --coverage --coverageReporters=text-lcov | coveralls",
    "lint": "eslint .  --ext .js",
    "lint-fix": "eslint --fix .  --ext .js",
    "prettier": "prettier --check **/*.js",
    "prettier:fix": "prettier --write **/*.js",
    "docker:prod": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up",
    "docker:dev": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up",
    "docker:test": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.test.yml up",
    "owasp": "owasp-dependency-check --project \"RECON-BACKEND\" -f JSON",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
```

Locally I am running my NodeJS project like this -

```
npm run build
npm run dev
```

On pm2 my project is invoked with this command -

```
pm2 start src/index.js
```

What changes do I need to make here so that it can run my typescript code. As I mentioned my `/built` folder has only 2 modules after the build command is run, it does not have an index.ts file